# Parsing a JSON API Call with php middlecoin.com

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, object

I'm trying to pull statistics from the middlecoin.com API. It returns a JSON response which I've loaded with the following code:

```
$site = 'http://www.middlecoin.com/json';    
$data = do_curl($site);
$json = json_encode(utf8_encode($data));
$results = utf8_decode(json_decode($json));
```

The do_curl function does what it says on the tin.

When I do a print_r($results) I get the following output (cut down somewhat as the standard response is over 3MB)..

```
{
  "totalPaidOut": "11000.04907121",
  "totalRejectedMegahashesPerSecond": "1511.7204",
  "totalImmatureBalance": "23.45909836",
  "totalMegahashesPerSecond": "22188.9121",
  "totalBalance": "177.32016523",
  "time": "2014-02-03 21:42:41",
  "report": [
    [
      "1KotnoAdpv8GGmqGcA6TmtM7S5M16HGqio",
      {
        "lastHourShares": 8491,
        "immatureBalance": "0.09777637",
        "lastHourRejectedShares": 579,
        "paidOut": "29.90940726",
        "unexchangedBalance": "0.85366875",
        "megahashesPerSecond": "158.2837",
        "bitcoinBalance": "0.80818376",
        "rejectedMegahashesPerSecond": "10.7933"
      }
    ],
    [
      "19458VPAWZ8sKpowv92CvvknRwszgj1j3J",
      {
        "lastHourShares": 8448,
        "immatureBalance": "0.10225497",
        "lastHourRejectedShares": 734,
        "paidOut": "1.40944696",
        "unexchangedBalance": "1.14475622",
        "megahashesPerSecond": "157.4821",
        "bitcoinBalance": "0.41326371",
        "rejectedMegahashesPerSecond": "13.6828"
      }
    ],
    [
      "1Du7Ao8VPBxnJ6sSmxySgVrM3ybcRCDpjY",
      {
        "lastHourShares": 6619,
        "immatureBalance": "0.19303031",
        "lastHourRejectedShares": 128,
        "paidOut": "7.69195129",
        "unexchangedBalance": "0.26796483",
        "megahashesPerSecond": "123.3871",
        "bitcoinBalance": "0.75187807",
        "rejectedMegahashesPerSecond": "2.3861"
      }
    ]
    ]
}
```

This is where the problem starts though, as I'm unable to do anything with the response. I've tried loading it into http://array.include-once.org/ and using the examples there to echo a result such as:

```
echo $data->report[0][0];
```

but no matter how I try and read the data nothing comes back (other than the occasional curly bracket?).

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of troubleshooting, I found the problem. Upping the memory limit resolved the issue.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```